# Student Schengen visa

Tags: germany, czech-republic

I have a Czech Republic student visa, can I visit someone in Germany with my student visa or student ID? Or like do I have to apply for another visa?

Answer (score 2):

A Schengen visa allows you to travel within the zone. As a non EU national you still need to carry your passport with visa, not just your student ID.

Comment: +1. Probably worth mentioning he's still subject to the 90/180 rule outside of the Czech Republic, though enforcement of that is minimal.